# REST API vs RESTful web services

Tags: rest-api

I am listening few words frequently. Those words are "REST API" and "RESTful Web-Services". But I am not able to figure out what to use when while conversing with team. Are there any significant difference between them?

Answer (score 5):

[The REST API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index.htm) is available out of the box for all Objects in all Orgs. You don't need to write any server-side code to use it. The endpoints look like:

`https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/001D000000INjVe​`

---

[Apex REST Web Services](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_rest.htm) are methods exposed on @annotated custom Apex classes which you create yourself. The endpoints look like:

`https://na1.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/namespace/ClassName/YourParam`

---

- both variants are subject to your total API request limits
- both variants require authentication

Answer (score 2):

I think that it depends on context including how you use these terms in your culture i.e. there are formal definitions but also slang definitions.

Formally, RESTful web-services should refer to the standards used in the implementation architecture but says nothing about the functionality provided e.g.

> Does your service use SOAP or RESTful webservices?

This statement doesn't define what those web-services do, just the structure they conform to. You can find more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

When salesforce.com talks about the REST API they're talking about an API implementation that conforms to RESTful standards. In short they're saying:

> We have an API and it uses RESTful concepts in it's architecture.

The [documentation for the REST API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index.htm) is therefore quite different.